# Clearing time out based on certain interval

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase-authentication, ionic3

I am writing a code to one check if a verification code has been typed within 1 min if not it will redirect to authentication page else it will continue with the sign up process. I am able to redirect to authentication after one minute but when the user types in verification and continuing with the sign up process it redirects the user to authentication page after one min, which means it doesn't clear the timeout. How can I clear it out?

```
    display: string = "display";
    firstAnimation: string = "first";
    secondAnimation: string = "second";
    thirdAnimation: string = "third";
    fifthAnimation: string = "fifth";
    bottomStyle: string = "bottom";
    msgNumber: any;
    token: any;
    userid: any;
    isSet: Boolean = true;
    timers:any;

    constructor(...) {

            ....    
            var count = 0;

            var that = this

            var timer = function () {
                let promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                    if (count === 1) {
                        that.firstAnimation = "first-para-animation";
                    } else if (count === 2) {
                        that.firstAnimation = "first-second-fire-        animation";
                        that.secondAnimation += " load-animation";
                    } else if (count === 3) {
                        // that.truthy = true;
                        that.bottomStyle = "no-margin"
                        that.fifthAnimation += " load-animation";
                    }

                    // check the length of count before pushing
                    if (count < messages.length) {
                        count += 1
                    } else {
                        clearInterval(interval)
                    }
                     if (count === 1) {

                        resolve()

                     }
                    return promise; 
                })
                promise.then(() => {
                    if (that.isSet) {
                        this.timers = setTimeout(function () {
                            var counter = 0;
                            console.log(count, 'count')
                            if (count == 3 && counter <= 3) {
                                that.redirect();
                            }
                            counter += count;
                        }, 60000);
                    }else{
                        clearTimeout(this.timers);
                    }
                })
            }
            //  setting the interval after how long it should call the timer function
            var interval = setInterval(timer, 1500)

        }

        redirect(){
            console.log('Fired yes!!!');
            let promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                this.toastCtrl.create({
                    message: "Ooops, took time verifing your code, try again.",
                    duration: 5000,
                    position: 'bottom'
                }).present();
                resolve()
            }).then(()=>{
                this.navCtrl.setRoot(AuthDevicePage);
            }) 
            return promise; 
        }



        verify() {
            let signInCredential = firebase.auth.PhoneAuthProvider.credential(this.verification_id, this.code);
            firebase.auth().signInWithCredential(signInCredential).then((user) => {
                this.app.loadUser().then(success => {
                    this.isSet = false;
                    ....

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

here is a solution after success fully completed your execution of code you have to call **clearInterval()** it will be able to stop the execution by calling the clearInterval() method
in your case you have to clear `clearInterval(interval)` when you done with your job
refer [w3school for more](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_clearinterval.asp)